# Failed to remove contact '{7A4C0334-B88B-47C4-9355-2F8777B2C0AE}' from any include lists

Tags: exm

We are trying to send email using EXM. We have created Segmented list and We can see contacts in the list. We have set up the email campaign. Initially we see all the contacts in the include list but after few mins it is becoming zero. When we checked EXM log we are getting many below errors:

```
332 23:58:35 ERROR Failed to process task. Pipeline threw an exception. Processing the task will be retried later.
Exception: Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Exceptions.MessageEventPipelineException
Message: Failed to remove  contact '{7A4C0334-B88B-47C4-9355-2F8777B2C0AE}' from any include lists
Source: Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Pipelines.RecipientListManagement.RemoveFromIncludeList.Process(RecipientListManagementPipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.PipelineHelper.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Tasks.MessageEventBaseTaskProcessor.OnProcess(ShortRunningTask task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Can someone help us with this?